# How to interpolate hourly data at second values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe **df** :

```
    L_Time                U_Time                Eval_Time         L_Flux U_Flux
    2018-05-01 04:30:00   2018-05-01 05:30:00   2018-05-01 05:23:45   100   200
    2018-05-01 07:30:00   2018-05-01 08:30:00   2018-05-01 07:44:11   100   200
```

*L_Flux* and *U_Flux* contains value of radiant flux at pandas timestamps *L_Time* and *U_Time* respectively. I want to interpolate the value of flux at *Eval_Time* which is in seconds. How can I do it properly with python or pandas. I tried to interpolate it with pandas and scipy linearly but that always gives me the middle value (150). I want to have the flux interpolated at second timestamp (*Eval_Time*) in accordance with its distance from the two hourly timestamps.

Comment: If Eval_Time is not between L_Time and U_Time, then you cannot interpolate. Is your data sample correct?

Comment: I updated the data sample. There was a typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to resample the data between *L_Time* and *U_Time* in seconds (upsampling) and then interpolate the upsampled flux values (previously NaN as they are missing) and extract the interpolated flux value at the *Eval_Time*.

```
INTERPOL_FLUX = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    df = pd.DataFrame( [(i[1],i[4]), (i[2],i[5])], columns = ['Times', 'Flux'] ) #Create a new dataframe with two Timestamps in a single row
    df = df.set_index('Times') #Set Timestamps as index of new dataframe
    df = pd.Series(df['Flux'], index = df.index)  #Squeeze dataframe to series
    interpolated  = df.resample('S').interpolate(method='linear') #Upsample data and interpolate (i needed linear ones)
    interpol_flux = interpolated.loc[ i[3] ] #Extract interpolated flux at Eval_Time
    INTERPOL_FLUX.append(interpol_flux) #Add this interpolated flux to an empty list

df['Eval_Flux'] = INTERPOL_FLUX  #Set this list as the Eval_Flux column
```

In concise,

```
INTERPOL_FLUX = []
for i in df.itertuples():
    df = pd.DataFrame( [(i[1],i[4]), (i[2],i[5])], columns = ['Times', 'Flux'] ).set_index('Times')
    df = pd.Series(df['Flux'], index = df.index)
    INTERPOL_FLUX.append(df.resample('S').interpolate(method='linear').loc[i[3]]) 

df['Eval_Flux'] = INTERPOL_FLUX
```

I thought it would be slow, but it is pretty fast.

Comment: You are iterating over a dataframe called `df`, and creating a new temporary dataframe within the loop, also called `df`. It is generally not a good idea to modify something you are iterating over. Doesn't this also give the same numeric result as my answer?

Comment: It is giving me the same result. I am grateful. In this way though, I can use linear or quadratic or any other method of interpolation easily which can come in handy any time. Still thanks a lot for your answer. @macaw_9227

Comment: You can't actually use quadratic interpolation when you only have 2 points of data (L and U). There really isn't any non-linear interpolation methods you can use unless you have more than 2 flux measurements on each row

Comment: My mistake ! I will keep that in mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do your own interpolation as it is between just 2 columns. Your data seems incorrect though, as you are asking to extrapolate in the second row. Regardless the following will give you an answer

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'L_Time':['2018-05-01 04:30:00','2018-05-03 07:30:00'],
    'U_Time':['2018-05-01 05:30:00','2018-05-01 08:30:00'],
    'Eval_Time':['2018-05-01 05:23:45','2018-05-01 07:44:11'],
    'L_Flux':[ 100 ,100],
    'U_Flux':[200,200]})

df['L_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['L_Time'])
df['U_Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['U_Time'])
df['Eval_Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Eval_Time'])

# The actual maths part - using times between U, L and Eval
df['Eval_Flux'] = df.L_Flux + (df.U_Flux - df.L_Flux)*(df.Eval_Time - df.L_Time)/(df.U_Time - df.L_Time)



               L_Time              U_Time          Eval_Time  L_Flux  U_Flux Eval_Flux
0 2018-05-01 04:30:00 2018-05-01 05:30:00 2018-05-01 05:23:45     100     200     189.583333   
1 2018-05-03 07:30:00 2018-05-01 08:30:00 2018-05-01 07:44:11     100     200     201.624704
```

Comment: Actually What i need is for each row, interpolate flux at Eval_Time where Eval_Time is between L_Time and U_Time and store this interpolated flux in the same row as a new column value. I have the same flux data in two rows so that I could emphasis the fact that due to different distances of Eval_Time from L_TIme and U_Time, different interpolated values are expected even for same U_FLux and L_Flux. @macaw_9227